# Requires permission private to package

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

When I execute the following command

> adb shell am startservice vision.fastfiletransfer/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService

it has the error

> Error while executing: am startservice vision.fastfiletransfer/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService
>   Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=vision.fastfiletransfer/com.android.tools.fd.runtime.InstantRunService }
>   Error: Requires permission private to package

And I use AndroidStudio 2.3 to debug,what is wrong？ What is more,my AndroidManifest is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vision.fastfiletransfer" >




    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="base.APP">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_share" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found two solutions that worked for me.

**Solution 1.** This doesn't need to change your SDK. You have to go **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run** and uncheck the first checkbox to disable Instant Run.

**Solution 2.** The emulator device has to give **autolunch permission** to the app. In most of devices and older SDK platforms, it is already set. But in my case (Nexus 5s, android-25), this permission doesn't exist anymore.
I had to choose an older device (older API) and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question in my project since upadted Android studio to 2.3 ,it seems that there is a studio's bug. You can try to use 2.2.3 .

Comment: Now I do not use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' ` in my project's build.gradle,it is ok. Magbe it is a bug.